# Problems will Dell Poweredge 2900

Tags: hard-drive, windows-sbs, dell-poweredge

My buddy is an IT professional who ended up with an extra PowerEdge 2900 server with a valid key for SBS 2003. He gifted it to me in return since he knew I wanted a personal home media server. I got 4 2TBseagate sata hdd, 2 enterprise and 2 standard desktop, set them in their trays and tried to install SBS 2003 with the iso burned to bootable dvds and it won't install because it can't detect and physical drives.

I've looked into the raid setup utility and it can't detect them either so it can't set up raid. I don't know if this is driver/firmware issue but I am not sure what else it could be. I have the bios loaded up right now and it just says there are unknown devices in sata port a and b. I'm not sure what I can do to get this running. Is it a problem with some of the hardware of the server or is it maybe the drives I am using for it? Is it driver or firmware problem? Do I need to update the bios and how can I do that with this server?

The end goal is to get it to be my home media server running Plex or something else to share with the other computers in my home and smart tvs. What can I do to get this running? Is there anyone that can help walk me through this set up?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Dell setup utilities.  There are several in the [OpenManage](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1968.dell-openmanage-downloads-explained) bundle that assist with various tasks such as RAID config and OS/patch/update installs